# How does the isnull() method work to return all rows that are missing in my data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, isnull

I'm new to Python and just trying to figure out how this small bit of code works. Hoping this'll be easy to explain without an example data frame.

My data frame, called `df_train`, contains a column called `Age`. This column is `NaN` for 177 records.

I submit the following code...

`df_train[df_train['Age'].isnull()]`

... and it returns all records that are missing.

Now if I submit `df_train['Age'].isnull()`, all I get is a Boolean List of values. How does the data frame object then work to convert this Boolean List to the rows we actually want?

I don't understand how passing the boolean list to the data frame again results in just the 177 records that we need - could someone please ELI5 for a newbie?

Comment: You are using what is called Boolean Masking. Basically, as in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), you are finding the indices where your condition is true (`df_train['Age'].isnull()`) then slicing your original dataframe based on those indices (`df_train[]`). As far as the syntax goes, it's just pandas' own way of easily implementing a mask, you can also use `df.mask()` or `df.where()` with `.loc` to acheive similar results

Comment: Thank you - any chance you could provide an example using `df.where()` with a `.loc`?

Comment: I mostly included that because you can get to the same result in a very contrived, ugly way. One _very silly_ example: Consider the dataframe `df=pd.DataFrame({'sport':['a','b','c','d'],'athletes':[12,34,56,78]})`, you can find the same subset with either `df.loc[df.where(df['athletes']>40)['athletes'].notnull()]]` or with `df[df['athletes']>40]`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create subsets of the `dataframe` you want to use. Suppose you want to use only those rows where `df_train['Age']` is not `null`. In that case, you have to select

```
df_train_to_use = df_train[df_train['Age'].isnull() == False]
```

Now, you may cross check any other column that you may want to use and have `nulls` like

```
 df_train['Column_name'].isnull().any()
```

If this returns `True`, you may go ahead and replace nulls with default values, average, zeros or whatever methods you prefer, usually put in application for machine learning programs.

Example

```
df_train['Column_name'].dropna()

df_train['Column_name'].fillna('') #for strings

df_train['Column_name'].fillna(0) #for int

df_train['Column_name'].fillna(0.0) #for float
```

Etc.

I hope this helps you explain.

Comment: Instead of `df_train['Age'].isnull() == False` it's more idiomatic to just use `notnull`, i.e. `df_train['Age'].notnull()`, or more generally using `~` to invert boolean masks when such a function is not available, i.e. `~df_train['Age'].isnull()`.

Comment: yes correct, I wanted to use same way question was asked to be more clear, but I totally agree with you and I will also prefer similar way to solve such problems.

Comment: This is a solid answer, but I think it misses the main question in the OP: "How does the data frame...convert this Boolean List to the rows we actually want?", i.e., boolean masking rather than just discussing the `isnull()` functionality